# GRPC streaming or WebSockets for chat app

Tags: websocket, stream, streaming, chat, grpc

I'm little bit confused about bidirectional working of gRPC. And I can't find any good explanation of it. Can somebody say/describe what is the difference between gRPC bidirectional streaming and websockets? Can I create fully functional chat application (server/client) using only gRPC with high load?